# Combining "set" and "block" in twig

Tags: twig

In my base.html.twig file I have some code like this:

```
<script src="http://mysite.local/{{ asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
```

Every twig file extends the base file.

At run time I want to be able to vary the value of "http://mysite.local" though. It will be the same across all files.

I would like to just have a constant in one of my configuration classes like `const HTTP = 'http://mysite.local';` which I can pass into the base.html.twig file.

I understand that may be difficult. But I could pass it into the sub twig files, and use a block to pass that into the base file I believe?

Is there a way I can do something like this?

```
// Sub twigs
{% block http %}
    {% set httpLink = 'http://mysite.local' %}
{% endblock %}

// Base twig

{% block http %}
{% endblock %}

<script src="{{ httpLink ~ asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: Check out twig globals, one of those may be more useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Would this approach work?:

base.html.twig:

```
<script src="{% block domain %}http://mysite.local/{% endblock %}{{ asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
```

In the Twig files that extend base.html.twig override the domain block:

```
{% block domain %}http://someotherdomain.com/{% endblock %}
```